# JBoss 7 + JPA doesn't inject entity manager to servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss, cdi

I'm trying to get my entity manager in a simple Hello World servlet, and I'm having issues.  I'm sure it's due some sort of mis-configuration, but can't find where it is.  I've got a basic servlet:

```
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public static final String HELLO_WORLD_WELCOME_MESSAGE = "This is the Hello World servlet!";

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        out.println(HELLO_WORLD_WELCOME_MESSAGE);

        List<Book> books = entityManager.createQuery("getBooks", LegacySermon.class).getResultList();
        for (Book book : books) {
            out.println(book.getTitle());
        }

        entityManager.close();
    }
```

A resource configuration:

```
public class Resources {

    @PersistenceContext
    @Produces
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

And a persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="grace">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

All configured.  However, the entityManager is no being injected, so I'm getting a NullPointerException when I attempt to call the .createQuery method.  What is my configuration missing?

Comment: Try adding the attribute transaction-type="JTA" in <persistence-unit >

Comment: That controls transaction management, not resource injection.

Comment: Yeah, tried that and I'm still getting the same thing.

Comment: I'm assuming you at least have a `WEB-INF/beans.xml` right?

Comment: Sigh... I forgot the beans.xml :-(.  @JohnAment, put that as an answer and I'll accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I've successfully used CDI to inject an EntityManager in a JEE6 container (such as JBoss 7.x).

Step 1: define your own qualifier. A good naming convention is to use the name of your persistence unit.

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({
    ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE
})
public @interface TestPU {
}
```

Step 2: slap that qualifier on your producer.

```
public class TestPUProducer {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "TestPU")
    @TestPU
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

Step 3: inject

```
@Inject
@TestPU
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Disclaimer: I never injected into a servlet, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work there.

Comment: Although this didn't wind up answering my question, I really like the use of this qualifier!

Comment: forgot beans.xml. DOH! I didn't even consider the possibility. Well good job figuring it out anyway.